# Transactions in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a windows service calling two different WCF services, both the services perform two different operations which need to be under the same transaction, which means both have to pass or both have to fail.

I started a Transaction in Windows Service, and purposefully made the second WCF service call fail, but to my surprise the operations were not getting rolled back.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: You may want to post some code concerning opening, committing and rolling back the transaction, because we won't be able to help you without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your WCF service operations should be annotated with `[TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)]`
2. The binding used by your WCF service should support transactions. Eg; wcfHttpBinding
3. The service method should work within a transaction, i.e. it should be annotated with 
   `[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired=true)]`

Comment: Is is mandatory to add the attribute, even though we are passing a transaction from client

Comment: Yes, it needs to be specified.

Comment: You should also add this:
[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired=true]

Comment: i have exposed my service via basicHttp binding, will that support Transactions.

Comment: No, unfortunately it won't. Only certain binding support transactions - and definitely not basicHttpBinding.